# Setting permissions to hide external javaScript

Tags: javascript, permissions, external

I am linking to external javascript files from an html file in the standard way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/example.js"></script>
```

Currently my file permissions are set to 0644 (User:Read, Write, Group:Read, World:Read) and if I navigate to the file in my browser I'm able to read all the javascript. If I change the permission to 0640 (User:Read, Write, Group:Read) when I navigate to the file in a browser I get 403 Permission Denied but the external javaScript link doesn't work in my html. How do I set it up so people can't see my javascript but my html can still link to it?

Comment: You can't. You're actually setting permissions for your web server user, on your own server, not external users.

Answer (score 0):

The browser has to be able to request the files from the web server; the web server must have read permissions in order for the scripts to be loaded.  There's no good way to protect your scripts from people reading them by setting server permissions that I'm aware of--because the operating system can't tell who (or what) is on the other side of the request from the web server executable.

If you're concerned that people will be getting access to intellectual property that you don't want exposed, your choices are obfuscation (not perfect) or moving that logic into a back-end process whose source can't be accessed by web users.  In general you have to work on the assumption that all the Javascript you write will be available for anyone to read.